# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object NEED Clarification

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

Not really sure what's causing this error when I am typing in the wrong password. I keep getting this error even if I add an any type for the error

```
import React from 'react';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { Message } from 'semantic-ui-react';

interface IProps {
  error: AxiosResponse;
  text?: string;
}

const ErrorMessage: React.FC<IProps> = ({ error, text }) => {
  return (
    <Message error>
      <Message.Header>{error.statusText}</Message.Header>
      {error.data && Object.keys(error.data.errors).length > 0 && (
        <Message.List>
          {Object.values(error.data.errors).flat().map((err, i) => (
            <Message.Item key={i}>(err: any, i)</Message.Item>
          ))}
        </Message.List>
      )}
      {text && <Message.Content content={text} />}
    </Message>
  );
};

export default ErrorMessage;
```

Comment: Please include error messages as text, not as pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `error.data.errors` is undefined.

Try replacing

```
error.data && Object.keys(error.data.errors)
```

with

```
error.data && error.data.errors && Object.keys(error.data.errors)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This has been a problem for me for awhile